# R scatter plot not plotting all of x axis

Tags: r, graph, axis, scatter-plot, percentage

I am having trouble figuring out how to make my x axis bigger and all of my points fit. For the x axis, my points range from 5.2 to 57.9. I would like to make my x axis from 0 to possibly 60.

Here is my code and a picture of what I see following:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
my.colors <- brewer.pal(7, "RdBu")

plot(x=log(ScatPlot$ownership..pct.), 
y=ScatPlot$firearm.law.stringency,
+      cex=(ScatPlot$death.rate),
+      col=my.colors[ScatPlot$state],
+      main="Death Rate given % Ownership and Law 
Stringency Per State", 
+      xlab="% Ownership", ylab="Death Rate")
```

[image]

Comment: Try `xlim = c(0, 60)`

Comment: @Tung She is using the log of x-values. So, `xlim` isn't going to help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of log transforming the x-values by yourself, you can ask R to do it for yourself. It would be much easier. You can do this using `log = "x"` in the `plot` function.

NOTE: you can not have 0 in the x-values then for the obvious infinite reason.

Here's an example using (some simulated data)

```
set.seed(1984)
xvals <- runif(15, 1, 600)
yvals <- runif(15, 5, 20)
plot(x=xvals, y=yvals, log = "x", xlim = c(1, 1000))
```

[image]

Comment: I think the OP is just looking for the xlim argument

Comment: @griffinevo I don't think so. Her `x-axis` goes only up to ~ 4, but she says is one value is close to 60. `log(60) = 4.09`.

Comment: Well either looking for xlim or has no idea what log() does, you are just telling them an alternative way to implement log transformation.

Comment: @emilyblegvad please clarify what you are looking for